# How to Query JSON Data in Ajax Request

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I have a json file as:

```
{"markers":[
    { "latitude":11.58655, "longitude":122.755402, "type":"A"},
    { "latitude":11.00698, "longitude":124.612801, "type":"B"},
    { "latitude":10.30723, "longitude":123.898399, "type":"A"},
    { "latitude":11.24775, "longitude":125.003502, "type":"C"},
    { "latitude":11.03693, "longitude":125.719498, "type":"Z"}
]}
```

and an ajax request as:

```
$.ajax({        
       type: "POST",
       url: 'data.txt',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data){  locations.length = 0;        
        for (p = 0; p < data.markers.length; p++) {  
locations.push(Array(data.markers[p].latitude,data.markers[p].longitude));               
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({                
position: new   

google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[p].latitude,data.markers[p].longitude),
map: map,  title:"marker "+p  });  }  }, 
error: function (xhr,status,errorStr) { 
alert("status="+status+", error="+errorStr)
 }     
});
```

which is working fine for me but I need to get the data based on their **TYPE**.Can you please let me know if there is  a way I can request based on a type like "**A**" so I get ONLY data that have a **TYPE = A**

Answer (score 2):

you can use `jQuery.grep()`

like this way

```
var filteredData = $.grep( data, function( d, i ) {
  return d.TYPE == 'A';
});
```

and loop through variable `filteredData`

check the docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

Comment: Hi Zzlalani, thanks but can you please let me know how to use the $.grep()? isn't' it gonna to slow down data retentive process?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (p = 0; p < data.markers.length; p++) { // this is your code
 if(data.markers[p].type == 'A'){
    //do stuff with type : A only
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Catalin and thanks for reply but where should I use this code?

Comment: this only filters the data you have. use it where you need the data TYPE = A you need. you din`t commented were you need :)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to check inside the loop

```
$.ajax({        
   type: "POST",
   url: 'data.txt',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){  locations.length = 0;        
    for (p = 0; p < data.markers.length; p++) {  
        if(data.markers[p].type === 'A'){
             locations.push(Array(data.markers[p].latitude,data.markers[p].longitude));               
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({                
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[p].latitude,data.markers[p].longitude), map: map,  title:"marker "+p  
             });  
       } 

    } 
}, 
error: function (xhr,status,errorStr) { 
   alert("status="+status+", error="+errorStr)
 }     
});
```